# Login with Facebook using custom button

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I've successfully use facebook SDK to login and get profile picture and name. But It's in the same view. I'm wondering how to change to another view after login.

AppDelegate.m file

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
[[FBSession activeSession] handleDidBecomeActive];
}
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
return [[FBSession activeSession]handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

viewController.m file

```
@interface loginViewController () <FBLoginViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBLoginView *loginView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *ProfilePic;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ProfileName;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.loginView.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark FBLoginviewDelegate
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
self.ProfilePic.profileID = user.objectID;
self.ProfileName.text = user.name;
}
-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
self.ProfilePic.profileID = nil;
self.ProfileName.text = nil;
}
```

Comment: u need to push the view controller from get data

Comment: if it yes use custom button action method

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, sorry I don't get it. The login button is actually a view called FBLoginView. How can I custom button action?

Comment: you should seriously consider just using parse.com for your project, if it involves 'facebook users' and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is custom button method :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
 //  self.loginView.delegate = self;    //hide one 
 }


 - (IBAction)butFacebooklogin:(id)sender
{
NSArray *permissions = @[@"email",@"user_about_me",@"user_status",@"user_location"];

// OPEN Session!
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                  FBSessionState status,
                                                  NSError *error) {
                                  // if login fails for any reason, we alert
                                  if (error) {

                                      //NSLog(@"error %@",error);
                                      // show error to user.

                                  } else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status)) {

                                      // no error, so we proceed with requesting user details of current facebook session.
                                      //NSLog(@"we are here");
                                      //NSLog(@"----%@",[session accessTokenData].accessToken);

                                    //  NSString *tok = [session accessTokenData].accessToken;
                                     // NSLog(@"tok 2");



                                      [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                                          if (error) {

                                              NSLog(@"error:%@",error);


                                          }
                                          else
                                          {

                                             /*

                                              NSString *userlocation=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.location[@"name"]];

                                              NSArray *items = [userlocation componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

                                              NSString *usercity, *userstate;

                                              if ([items count]>0) {
                                                  usercity=[items objectAtIndex:0];

                                                  userstate=[items objectAtIndex:1];

                                                  userstate = [userstate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
                                              }
                                              else
                                              {
                                                  usercity=@"";
                                                  userstate=@"";
                                              }

                                              */

                                              NSString *email=[user objectForKey:@"email"];



                                              if (email.length>0) {
                                                  email=[user objectForKey:@"email"];
                                              }

                                              else
                                              {
                                                  email=@"";
                                              }





                                              NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_id=%@&fname=%@&lname=%@",email,user.first_name,user.last_name,nil];

                                               NSLog(@" RequestString for get login details: %@",userUpdate); 

  // here add ur segue or push view method
                                          }
                                      }];
                                      // [self promptUserWithAccountName];   // a custom method - see below:
                                  }
                              }];
    }
```

Comment: So you mean that the ability of custom button is more than FBLoginView?

Comment: FBloginview redirect to the same view after that we move on any customization, in this custom button action method we can customized ourself

Answer (score 1):

In latest FB SDK this doesn't work anymore. FBSession (along with FBRequest) class has been dropped.

Now you have to use [FBSDKLoginManager](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/) class and its method

```
- (void)logInWithReadPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions handler:(FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler)handler;
```

Sample code of login and getting user info:

```
FBSDKLoginManager* lm = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[lm logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

    // no error, so get user info
    if (!error && !result.isCancelled)
    {  
      [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
       startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"fetched user:%@  and Email : %@", result,result[@"email"]);
         }
     }];
   }

}];
```

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879330/fb-4-0-fbsession-openactivesessionwithreadpermissions-replacement)