# How to assign different delegates for FBlogin to two different view controllers in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, delegates, facebook-ios-sdk

I have two view controllers, one uses `FBLoginView` and its delegates and they are handled in the same class. However, I have another `viewcontroller` which uses custom button to initiate `FBLogin` and hence I am not able to assign the delegates to this class. When the `FBLogin` is successful it comes to delegate calls in first view controller. I want to handle the events seperately for second view controller. For example: First view controller is login having a `FBLogin` default view and second view controller is Signup having a custom button and implementing `FBSession` methods so that it takes to Facebook app or safari mobile website. How can I achieve the login delegates methods to be called in Signup page seperately so that I can do view handling exquisitely for this page?

Code in the button action for signup page are:

```
// If the session state is any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
    || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

    // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
    // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    // If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
} else {
    // Open a session showing the user the login UI
    // You must ALWAYS ask for public_profile permissions when opening a session
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
}
```

Here `allowLoginUI` is set to `YES` so that it redirects to login for Facebook.

For login page, code is:

```
self.loginButton.delegate = self;
self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
```

Hence, these delegates are called in login page even when I do call button action from signup,

```
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
}
```

Comment: r u try for the Facebook login in login and signup page

Comment: show ur login page and signup page codings,

Comment: adding the code in the question.

Comment: customize something urself , no need of loginViewFetchedUserInfo bz u r using custom button in signup page na, if yes use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602504/login-with-facebook-using-custom-button/25603344#25603344

Comment: yes with link mentioned it is handled in completion block. it goes there. but it also comes to delegate methods of login page which I don't want. What should be done for it doesn't go there? Or should i keep some check so that it doesn't do anything on the logindelegate methods.

Comment: finally kept a check if it is coming from signup page and handled it , but couldn't find a way not to call delegate methods of loginpage in this case.