# FaceBook Login not work According to my need

Tags: ios, iphone

I am creating an app in which I perform Facebook login. I am using storyboard in my App. Facebook login is work, When I click on FBLoginView then login is perform. The Confirm Screen is shown but when I click on ok button then I return on the login page but I want to go on my HomePage. In AppDelegate I store the data of user and use this code:

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
appDelegate.firstName = user.first_name;
appDelegate.LastName = user.last_name;
appDelegate.emailID = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray array];
[data addObject:appDelegate.firstName];
[data addObject:appDelegate.LastName];
[data addObject:appDelegate.emailID];
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[self didMoveToParentViewController:home];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:home animated:YES];
}
```

home is the object of HomeViewController.
How can I go to HomeViewController page.

Now custom Button code is that:

```
- (IBAction)fblogging:(id)sender {
NSArray *permissions = @[@"email",@"user_about_me",@"user_status",@"user_location"];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                  FBSessionState status,
                                                  NSError *error) {

                                  if (error) {

                                  } else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status)) {


                                      [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                                          if (error) {

                                              NSLog(@"error:%@",error);


                                          }
                                          else
                                          {
                                              NSString *email=[user objectForKey:@"email"];

                                              if (email.length>0) {
                                                  email=[user objectForKey:@"email"];
                                              }

                                              else
                                              {
                                                  email=@"";
                                              }

                                              NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_id=%@&fname=%@&lname=%@",email,user.first_name,user.last_name,nil];

                                              NSLog(@" RequestString for get login details: %@",userUpdate); 

                                              // here add ur segue or push view method
                                               [self.navigationController pushViewController:home animated:YES];
                                          }
                                      }];
                                      // [self promptUserWithAccountName];   // a custom method - see below:
                                  }
                              }];
```

}
    enter code here

Comment: if u use login view it comes at the same view , use custom button it redirect to the page whatever u need

Comment: if u use custom button use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602504/login-with-facebook-using-custom-button/25603344#25603344

Comment: I do that, yet it return on login page, is there any mistake in my storyboard or in my code to remove? Can you tell me?

Comment: in which method in loginview or custom button method

Comment: I write    [self.navigationController pushViewController:home animated:YES];

Comment: can u updated your code here,

Comment: I write    [self.navigationController pushViewController:home animated:YES];

Comment: - (IBAction)fblogging:(id)sender {
    NSArray *permissions = @[@"email",@"user_about_me",@"user_status",@"user_location"];

    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {                                      if (error) { } else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status)) {[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {

Comment: if (error) {NSLog(@"error:%@",error); } else{ NSString *email=[user objectForKey:@"email"];
 if (email.length>0){email=[user objectForKey:@"email"];
 }else{email=@"";}
NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_id=%@&fname=%@&lname=%@",email,user.first_name,user.last_name,nil];
NSLog(@" RequestString for get login details: %@",userUpdate); 
// here add ur segue or push view method

Comment: ya correct NSLog(@" RequestString for get login details: %@",userUpdate); after this line u pass ur VC using (segue or push method)

Comment: can you help me in also it-> i fetch web service data  if web service data in this form {"id":3393,"content":"Hello, World!"} then I use  self.id.text = [[myobjs objectForKey:@"id"] stringValue];
             self.myContent.text = [myobjs objectForKey:@"content"];                      but i want to fetch <id>3393</id> <content>hello</content>     then how i fetch