# FB 4.0 - FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions replacement

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, deprecated

I was previously using Facebook SDK 3.x for iOS. My code has `FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` in various places, and now that I am using version 4.x I'm not sure what the replacement is

I am thinking it is the login methods but I'm not sure what the 1:1 replacement/equivalent is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. You can convert over to using the following `FBSDKLoginManager` method:

```
- (void)logInWithReadPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions handler:(FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler)handler;
```

Or if looking for publishing permissions you can use:

```
- (void)logInWithPublishPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions handler:(FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler)handler;
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how to use it?